# Traverse directories, compare the tree, delete files missing on one side only

Tags: bash, delete

Trying to figure out how to remove any `.mp3`'s in the `/out/` directory hierarchy that do not have matching `.flac`'s in the corresponding `/in/` folder... and also any other files in the `/out` hierarchy that don't have corresponding files in `/in/'. The only extension to mutate here are those two but there will be other files (like`.jpg`,`.png`, etc.)

```
#!/bin/bash
find /in>/tmp/in.txt
sed 's/.flac/.mp3/g; s+/in+/out+g' /tmp/in.txt>/tmp/inx.txt
find /out>/tmp/out.txt
grep -vxF -f /tmp/inx.txt /tmp/out.txt>/tmp/clean.txt
while read line; do rm "$line"; done < /tmp/clean.txt
```

Final cleanup on empty folders. This line kind of "cheats" to remove any empty directories. It would be better if 'rm' above could be used to remove a file or folder above but that would be dangerous?

```
find /out/. -depth -type d -exec rmdir {} + 2>/dev/null
```

So far, I've figured out those first 2 can be lumped together as so:

```
find /in | sed 's/.flac/.mp3/g; s+/in+/out+g'>/config/inx.txt
```

I tried using:

```
grep -vxF -f /tmp/inx.txt `find /out`>/tmp/clean.txt
```

But I got the error: Argument list too long.

Is there any way to pipe all these things together and save some processing time? So far, it takes almost 10 minutes to complete the operation.

---

Next attempt, works except on files/folders with single quote marks (the IFS at least gets it to handle whitespaces):

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'; set -f
for mp in $(find /out)
do
    mf="${mp%/out/}/in/"  # Change /out/ to /in/
    ff="${mf%mp3}flac"    # Convert mp3 filename to flac
    [[ ! -f "$ff" ]] && echo rm "$mp"
done
unset IFS; set +f
```

---

Alright. I think this is it. And at this point, edited my original question to reflect that it's checking more than just music files.

```
#!/bin/bash
find /out -type f -name '*' -exec bash -c '
    for mp in "$0" "$@";
    do
        mf="${mp#/out/}";               # Strip /out/ base prefix leaving relative pathname
        if [ "${mf##*.}" = "mp3" ]; then
                mf="${mf%.mp3}.flac";   # convert filename to flac if it was mp3
        fi;
        [[ ! -f "/in/$mf" ]] && echo rm "$mp";
    done
' {} +
```

---

Starting to understand how bash shorthand works.

```
#!/bin/bash
find /out -type f -exec bash -c '
    for mp in "$0" "$@";
    do
        mf="${mp#/out/}";       # Strip /out/ base prefix leaving relative pathname
        [[ "${mf##*.}" == "mp3" ]] && mf="${mf%.mp3}.flac";     # convert filename to flac if it was mp3
        [[ ! -f "/in/$mf" ]] && echo rm "$mp";      # remove /out/ file if no match
    done
' {} +
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `grep` or `sed`. The essence of the process can be shown for a single directory like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for op in /out/*.mp3
do
    mp="${mp##/out/}"       # Strip /out/ base prefix leaving relative pathname
    fp="${mf%.mp3}.flac"    # Convert mp3 name to flac
    [[ ! -f "/in/$fp" ]] && echo rm "$op"
done
```

Since you need this for a directory tree you need to apply this to each directory in turn:

```
find /out -type f -name '*.mp3' -exec bash -c '
    for mp in "$0" "$@";
    do
        mp="${mp#/out/}";
        fp="${mf%.mp3}.flac";
        [[ ! -f "/in/$fp" ]] && echo rm "$op";
    done
' {} +
```

If your `find` doesn't support `-exec ... +` replace the `+` with `';'`. In both cases remove `echo` when you're happy it's going to remove the right files.

Comment: It took me a second to figure this out.  But I need the cleaner to traverse multiple layers of folders.  You got me on a different track...

Comment: Thank you. Had to edit the question further but you put me on the right track and with a bunch of echo's for debugging... I got it.  Wow. That should cut the time down a lot.  Thank you!  Is there anything I messed-up? Anything to streamline further?

Comment: The `-name '*'` in your edited question can be removed, and I'd be inclined to replace your `if ... fi` with `[[ "${mf##*.}" == "mp3" ]] && mf="${mf%.mp3}.flac"`.

Comment: Got it.  I really appreciate it.  if you're wondering what I'm working on: https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/darkpoet78/flac2mp3

Comment: Really, really appreciate it.  I've now had a chance to test it.  My old one took 10-20 minutes to step through 25,000 files.  With your help, it finishes in seconds!  Thank you thank you!  Is clicking the checkmark all I can do to up your rep?